# Excel - (non VBA) - Highlight Set of Columns based on value of another cell

Tags: excel

I'm looking for a non-VBA advice/help. I want to highlight a range of columns based on the value of a key cell.

e.g. If the key cell has a value of 6, then I want to highlight the columns where it has the same key lookup value.[Example of what I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6BGz.png) If I change the key cell value to 5, then the column where 5 is labeled will be highlighted.

Initially I used the conditional formatting rules to highlight the columns based on the key cell value, but I think I can only do one column at a time. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a formula-based Conditional formatting rule.

Eg:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, give me a second to look it over.

Comment: Regarding the Match formula in this code - I noticed that cell B6 is locked. I have to write this code out 50 times and the key cell changes. I noticed that when I unlocked the cell, it doesn't show what I am expecting.

Comment: Your question only mentions a single cell, so you'll need to explain exactly how the values in different "key" cells should be considered.